# How to loop though Record<K, T>

Tags: typescript, foreach

I have `Records` type of [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt):

```
export interface List {
  name: string;
  title: string;
}

export type RecordType
= 'recordOne'
| 'recordTwo'
| 'recordThree';

export const Records: Record<RecordType, List> = {
  recordOne: {
    name: 'Name1',
    title: 'Ausi bere ut erit adeo enim an suae'
  },
  recordTwo: {
    name: 'Name2',
    title: 'Petebat proprie suo methodo'
  },
  recordThree: {
    name: 'Name3',
    title: 'Petebat proprie suo methodo inscitiae'
  }
}
```

I want to search for record with specific text but in order to do that I need to loop through the `Records` so how would you do that? I mean how would you loop thought the `Records` ?

Basically that is what I want:

```
findMatchingTitle(myString) {
   let title = '';
   this.Records.foreach(x => {

     if(myString.includes(x.title)) {
       title = x.title;
     }
   });

  return title;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Object.entries`, `Object.values` or `Object.keys`

Answer (score 8):

Generally to loop through Objects you can do:

```
for(let prop in obj) console.log(obj[prop])
```

However typescript wont let you do that with no implicit any, which is why you'd have to type cast:

```
for (let prop in Records) console.log((Records as any)[prop]);
```

Another way to loop through an Object and compare properties is with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) as shown below

```
function findMatchingTitle(myString: string): string {
  for (let index in Object.keys(Records)) {
    let title: string = Object.values(Records)[index].name;
    if (title.includes(myString))
      return title;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Alternatively, for an exact search it would be:

```
function findMatchingTitle(myString: string): string {
  for (let index in Object.keys(Records)) {
    let title: string = Object.values(Records)[index].name;
    if (title === myString)
      return title;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys` and `Object.values` to loop through the `Record< RecordType, List>` type.

Just use `Object.values` to return all the values on the `Records` and then filter by the title as follows:

```js
function findMatchingTitle(title: string): List {
  return Object.values(Records).find((i: List) => i.title === title);
};
```

Would strongly recommend defining your argument and function return types in typescript as well.

Comment: Additionally: If you want to iterate over _both_ (So over key-value pairs), use **Object.entries**.

Answer (score 2):

For me to iterate over a Record<string, string> and needing both the key and the value, this did the trick:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myRecord)) {
    formData.append(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really related to TS, in order to search for the title, I would first get the records values as array, and use the Array.find to look for the title.

if I found one, I will get its title

```js
const records = {
  recordOne: {
    name: 'Name1',
    title: 'Ausi bere ut erit adeo enim an suae'
  },
  recordTwo: {
    name: 'Name2',
    title: 'Petebat proprie suo methodo'
  },
  recordThree: {
    name: 'Name3',
    title: 'Petebat proprie suo methodo inscitiae'
  }
}

const findMatchingTitle = str => Object.values(records).find(record => record.title.includes(str))?.title

console.log(findMatchingTitle("inscitiae"))
```